# Inserting Multiple Blank Cells Below Cells Containing Data Series

Tags: excel

I have a column of data (column A) and I want to spread the data out in column C, so that there are three blank cells below each new number. In the case of duplicate numbers, one extra blank cell would be added. I cannot devise a formula that will accomplish this.

In the spirit of a picture is worth a thousand words, here is a link showing how I would like column C to appear, as derived from column A:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcWNT.jpg)

Comment: This would be fairly easy if not for the 'extra row for duplicates' rule which demands an iterative calculation cycle. Why not simply write a vba sub procedure or user defined function?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not well-versed in vba structure. I suspected that the duplicate aspect would be a real problem. However, I can't even create more than one space between dissimilar numbers. How would one do three spaces with every change in a number? That might get me most of the way to my goal.

Comment: Put this in C2 and fill down `=INDEX(A:A, INT(ROW(8:8)/4))`

Comment: Now you just have to remove duplicates while adding an extra row when there is a blank. The closest I got was `=INDEX(A:A, INT(ROW(OFFSET(8:8, SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A$2:INDEX(A:A, INT(ROW(8:8)/4)), A$2:INDEX(A:A,INT(ROW(8:8)/4))&""))-COUNTA(A$2:INDEX(A:A, INT(ROW(8:8)/4))), 0))/4)+COUNTA(A$2:INDEX(A:A, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)+2))-SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A$2:INDEX(A:A, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)+2), A$2:INDEX(A:A, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)+2)&"")))` which covers the duplicate at 7 but not 14.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Once you get it working correctly, the whole needs to be doubled up because you have to test with an IF so you don't show the extra numbers in between.

Comment: Like I say, it doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: The second formula (which returned an error) won't be necessary because I do need to deal with the duplicates. However, the first, simpler, formula does give me something that I think I can make work. Not perfect, but moves me a lot closer to the goal. Thanks.